# How to update the Adapter using Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my project i have to update the Adapter when file download completed.
I have created a class to download the file.I have used a broadcast receiver which executed when file download is completed.The code which i used to download the file is as follows.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent)
    {
       //buttonText.setText("");

    //    GlobalVariable.downloading_pos.add()

        GlobalVariable.downloadingFlag=1;
        GlobalVariable.downloading_started=0;
        GlobalVariable.downloading_pos.clear();
        Log.d("Size==", "onReceive: "+GlobalVariable.downloading_pos.size());

        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: "+ GlobalVariable.downloading_started);

     //   GlobalVariable.downloaded_position.put(downloaded_position,downloaded_position);

      //  GlobalVariable.download_AudioID.put(audio_file, audio_file);

      //   GlobalVariable.download_AudioID.put(audio_file, audio_file);
        Log.d("dsvvv==", "onReceive: " + downloadFileName.split("\\.")[0]);
        //  GlobalVariable.download_file.add(downloadFileName.split("\\.")[0]);

        GlobalVariable.download_file.add(downloadFileName.split("\\.")[0]);

        if (!apkStorage.isFile()) {
            buttonText.setEnabled(false);
            // z  myBookingListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            buttonText.setText("Audio Downloaded");
            buttonText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_button_mybooking);
            buttonPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orange_button_mybooking);
        }
        else
        {
            buttonText.setText(R.string.downloadFailed);//If download failed change button text
            buttonText.setEnabled(true);
            buttonText.setText(R.string.downloadAgain);//Change button tex
        }

        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
        q.setFilterById(extras.getLong(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID));
        Cursor c = downloadManager.query(q);

        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
            if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL)
            {
                // process download
              //String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
                // get other required data by changing the constant passed to getColumnIndex

                Uri uri = downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(referenceId);

                if (from_flag.equals(ctxt.getString(R.string.my_booking)))
                {
                   // Fragdash_mybooking.adapterReset();
                    GlobalVariable.download_AudioID.put(downloadFileName.split("\\.")[0], downloadFileName.split("\\.")[0]);
                }
                else if (from_flag.equals(ctxt.getString(R.string.my_invitation)))
                {
                 //   Fragdash_invitation.adapterReset();
                    GlobalVariable.download_AudioID.put(downloadFileName.split("\\.")[0], downloadFileName.split("\\.")[0]);
                }

            }
        }
        c.close();
        Log.e("INSIDE", "" + referenceId);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif)
                        .setContentTitle("Ucine")
                        .setContentText("Download completed");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(455, mBuilder.build());

    }
};
```

Comment: do you want to update adapter while activity is opened?

Comment: No, in adapter itself.File is downloading in background thread, when download is completed the broadcast receiver call. When Broadcast receiver call at the same time i want to update the Adapter.

Comment: Are you showing list in a fragment or activity?

Comment: @SanjayKumar I am showing it in  Fragment.

Comment: You need to create a local broadcast listener in fragment. When fragment is opened just register your local broadcast in onresume method

Comment: I have to update only the text of a particular position  button.